# Need help in adding title to table

Tags: tables, captions

I am trying to name the table as shown in the image attached herewith but unable to succeed. Please help.[image: Table]

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.0cm,
bottom=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Variation of color with temperature}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
\textbf{COLOR}  & \textbf{TEMP.,\textbf{$^{o}F$}}\\
\hline
Faint Red  & 950\\
Dark red & 1150\\
Dark cherry & 1175\\
Cherry red&1300\\
Bright cherry&1475\\
Dark orange&1650\\
Orange&1750\\
Yellow&1800\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\\\
\end{table}
\blindtext{10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, there's a gap between the table and the text that follows. How do I reduce this gap?

Comment: Did you try `\caption{your text}`? If this is not what you are looking for, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I did. But the title takes centre alignment. I am trying to name the table exactly as apparent in the image attached.

Comment: Then please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). If you need such an exact replication of the style shown, your documentclass and packages will be important to know.

Comment: The `threeparttable` package might be interesting.

Comment: @samcarter I am really sorry, it's just my second-day hands-on Latex, and I honestly did not have any idea what MWE is. I have edited the question and include the code I wrote and the output I obtained. Thanks.

Comment: @AmarSheelwant Thanks for adding the relevant code! Does the answer below solve your problem or do you need further help?

Comment: @samcarter It's a great answer. However, I am too new to Latex to understand the role that different codes (and packages) have on the output mentioned in the below solution. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `floatrow` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, floatrow, threeparttable}
\usepackage{textcomp, siunitx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\normalfont}{\sffamily}
 \centering
\sisetup{detect-family, mode = text, table-format=4.0, table-number-alignment=left}
 \captionsetup{font={bf, sf}}
 \floatsetup{captionskip=6pt}
 \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Variation of color with temperature}\label{colortp}}%
 {\begin{tabular}{lS}
\toprule
 \textbf{COLOR} & {\textbf{TEMP.,\,\textdegree F}} \\
 \midrule
 Faint red &950 \\
 Dark red & 1150 \\
 Dark cherry & 1175 \\
 Cherry red & 1300 \\
 Bright cherry & 1475 \\
 Dark orange & 1650 \\
 Orange & 1750 \\
 Yellow & 1800 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Is better `^\circ` or `\textdegree` to denotate the unit of measure of the temperature?

Comment: I think `\circ` is a bit large when you compare it to the unicode degree character (even if set in `\scripscriptstyle`).

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks a ton for the solution!

Comment: @AmarSheelwant I am happy that you have finded an optimal solution. My best regards.